# Arrow through text in Math mode

Tags: arrows

So I know the `cancel` package lets you put a diagonal arrow through text in Math mode, but how could I achieve the same result but with a horizontal arrow?

Comment: The result doesn't seem pretty: the arrow tip will confuse with the text underneath.

Comment: @egreg I'm imaging an image that, if I try to approximate it with ASCII, would look like:  x -f-u-n-c-t-i-o-n-> y.  Of course I don't always want the text that is overlapping with arrow to be 'function' but this gives a sense of what I want it to look like.  But the arrow-head should stick out some distance to the right of the text so that there isn't that confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, using `\xrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\arrowcancel}[1]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \sbox0{$\mspace{3mu}{#1}\mspace{6mu}$}%
    {\vphantom{#1}
     \ooalign{%
       $\xrightarrow{\hspace{\wd0}}$\cr
       \hidewidth\box0 \hidewidth\cr
     }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$x\arrowcancel{abc}y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm playing around with it and can't figure out how I might automatically make the arrow head extend just a little farther to the right.  I know I can do it if I use the command `\arrowcancel{abc\,\,}` but is there a way to automate this effect?

Comment: @Addem Change `\mspace{6mu}` into `\mspace{9mu}` or so.